# Why is HTML encoding apostrophes in Rails 2 giving an unexpected result?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encode, apostrophe

I'm using `h` to HTML encode some text in Rails 2, but I'm having problems with apostrophes. To be more exact, I'm finding that my apostrophes end up as `&#39;` which is obviously not want I want to display.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? My research has implied HTML encoding shouldn't affect apostrophes.

Comment: Does it really output `&#39;` to what the user sees (i.e. `&amp;#39;`), or is this shown when viewing the html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting question. I'm seeing an inconsistency in how `h` AKA `html_escape` handles apostrophe AKA `"'"`.

According to the RDoc for [ERB::Util](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/erubis/2.6.6/ERB/Util) 2.6.6:

```
ESCAPE_TABLE = { '&'=>'&amp;', '<'=>'&lt;', '>'=>'&gt;', '"'=>'&quot;', "'"=>'&#039;', }

gem list erubis
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
erubis (2.6.6)
```

In IRB I see:

```
Welcome to IRB. You are using ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]. Have fun ;)
>> require 'erb' #=> true
>> ERB::Util.html_escape("foo'bar") #=> "foo'bar"
>> ERB::Util.html_escape('foo"bar') #=> "foo&quot;bar"
```

---

EDIT:

Heh, it's a bug, or at least an inconsistency, in the `h` method. Here's the source:

```
# File 'lib/erubis/helpers/rails_helper.rb', line 342

def h(value)
  value.to_s.gsub(/[&<>"]/) {|s| ESCAPE_TABLE[s] }
end
```

Notice the string being passed to `gsub` doesn't contain `"'"`? That means the lookup for ESCAPE_TABLE doesn't get called for single-quote/apostrophe.

And, we all know the crux of the biscuit is the apostrophe. :-)

I expect that if I look at the definition for `h` or `html_escape` in your version of Rails, we'll find the apostrophe is included in that string.

The fix is either to upgrade your ERB/Erubis, or override the `h`/`html_escape` definition to be correct. You can use the definition above as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem in Rails 4 where apostrophes would display as `&#39;`
The problem actually seems to be that I was using the `truncate`function to display the text. Once that was removed, the apostrophes display as expected.

In this case adding `escape:false` as option to truncate solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails 3 does `h` automatically. This is not needed anymore. Use

```
<%= @post.body %>
```

instead of

```
<%=h @post.body %>
```

If you do want to output anything without escaping it, use `raw`:

```
<%=raw @post.body %> <!-- For example, for use in a plaintext format */
```

Comment: afraid I'm using rails 2, so problem still stands.  I'll edit my question to include this info.

Comment: @tiswas I'll leave this answer here for Rails 3 users with the same problem. I'll make it Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

From looking the source code in `actionpack/lib/action_view/erb/util.rb` apostrophes aren't encoded, only `& > < "` characters.

My guess is somewhere in your Rails app a library/plugin/gem has redefined `html_escape` or the `HTML_ESCAPE` constant. You should also check your data directly in the database to ensure that it hadn't already been encoded when saved.